# Distribute ssh keys using ansible

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I have deployed user accounts to our test machines and also made their home directories and generated ssh keys. Users are created as expected.

[image]

**How can i copy their keys to authorized keys of each server so they can do ssh without entering the password or at least using passpharase?**

```
---
- hosts: all
  remote_user: root
  vars:
    users:
      - username: test9
      - username: test8
      - username: test7

  tasks:
  - name: Adding users
    user:
      name: "{{ item.username }}"
      state: present
      createhome: yes
      generate_ssh_key: yes
      ssh_key_bits: 2048
    with_items: "{{ users }}"
```

I tried this:

```
---
- hosts: all
  remote_user: root
  vars:
    users:
      #- username: test9
      - username: test8
      - username: test7

  tasks:
  - name: Adding users
    authorized_key: user='{{item.username}}' state=present key="{{ lookup('file', '/home/{{ item.username}}/.ssh/id_rsa.pub')}}" manage_dir=no
    with_items: "{{ users }}"
```

and getting the error message saying  `message: could not locate file in lookup: /home/test8/.ssh/id_rsa.pub"}` is it trying to locate the file in ansible server rather than those hosts? how can i fix that ? sorry, i am new to ansible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [Ansible's docs on Lookups](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbooks_lookups.html#lookups)

> Lookups occur on the local computer, not on the remote computer.

So Ansible is attempting to find your users' keys on "Ansible Server".

Personally I wouldn't use the `generate_ssh_key` parameter in your user task.

1. Each user will have a different key for each server.
2. You will have
   to distribute the keys to each user since they won't be able to get
   on the server in the first place.
3. If you really want to be secure
   with your users' private keys the best method would be [not to
   distribute them at all](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/101562).

I would instead give instructions to the users on how to generate keys and ask them to provide me their **public key** once generated.  Then you can pass the pub key to Ansible either through lookup or as a variable.

However if you're set on your method I wouldn't use the `authorized_keys` module.  Instead I'd just copy the file.

```
- name: copy pub key to authorized_keys
  copy:
    src: "/home/{{ item.username }}/.ssh/id_rsa.pub"
    dest: "/home/{{ item.username }}/.ssh/authorized_keys"
    user: "{{ item.username }}"
    group: "{{ item.username }}"
    mode: "0644"
    remote_src: True
  with_items: "{{ users }}"
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply. I guess I will go with this approach i,e. asking the public key of users and distribute them to the servers.

Comment: I cant ssh using the password mentioned in - user module's password parameter. could you tell me why ? or how can i reset them

Comment: Could be any number of reasons.  Can you make another question if you're still having trouble?